# vmware starting failed in kali linux

Tags: kali-linux

VMware starting failed and kernels headers for 4.9.0-kali3-amd64 not found. So i need to install kernels headers for 4.9.0-kali3-amd64

```
root@kali:~# apt install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this repository to your `sources.list`

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

Enter this command

```
apt-get update
```

And the whole of this command

```
apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
```

When the installation has complete just restart your pc or laptop and enjoy

Comment: I would recommend you read http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories which says *Any additional repositories added to the Kali sources.list file will most likely BREAK YOUR KALI LINUX INSTALL.*